# SQL Count number of values given compound condition on row

Tags: sql, count

I have a table as follows:

```
User ID  Service
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        3
3        5
3        3
4        3
5        2
```

How could I construct a query where I would count all the user ids that have a service of 3 and at least one other service?

In the above table, the query I'm interested in would return 3 because user ids 1, 2 and 3 have service of 3 and at least one other service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MS SQL:

```
select count(*)
from UserService
where 
    ServiceId = 3 and
    UserId in (select UserId from UserService where ServiceId != 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** In response to comments:

```
select count(*) from (

select userId
  from theTable
 group by userId
having sum(case when service = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when service <>3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0

) x
```

Comment: +1 but the OP wants the count rather than the specific `userId`s

Comment: I'm after the count rather than the user_ids (as mentioned by Martin)

Comment: @TimO - You could just shove the query in Ken's answer into a derived table or CTE and `select count` from that but what RDBMS are you on?

Comment: @Tim O: Then either variant would do the job. And Ken has already implemented one of them for you.